# apt-get doesn't completely uninstall dependencies which it has installed

Tags: apt, package-management

I ran `sudo apt-get install tor` which installed these packages:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tor tor-geoipdb torsocks
```

But when I tried to remove it with `sudo apt-get remove tor` - providing the same package name (only `tor`), it is missing `torsocks`:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  tor tor-geoipdb
```

So `torsocks` stays installed - I really hate this behavior. Why is it happening and how can I fix it? *How can I be sure everything what was installed gets removed?*

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache rdepends torsocks`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To uninstall a package with all its dependencies you can use `--auto-remove`

`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove tor`

Comment: I guess it's not possible to uninstall exactly the packages that were installed by the previous `apt-get install *` command. Because this will uninstall all dependencies that aren't needed, but maybe I want to keep some of them. Nevermind, thanks for the answer.

Comment: See my answer, you can (and should) mark the ones you want to keep as manually installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `sudo apt-get autoremove` to uninstall everything that was automatically installed and is no longer needed.

I guess `tor-geoipdb` gets removed because it depends in `tor` so it can't be installed without `tor` being installed.

Now `torsocks` can be installed on it's own but is no longer required to being installed. So it can be automatically removed.

You can query the state of a package (auto or manual) can be changed with `apt-mark`.